# Center parent div with dynamic and set width child divs

Tags: html, css, dynamic, width, center

This contains both my logo and navigation bar inside the main parent div.

The logo has a set width and the navigation bar has a dynamic width. The navigation bar is always 100px to the right of the logo.

At the moment it is perfect except it is constantly at the left of the screen. I would like for it to be identical in every aspect, except that it is at the center of the screen.

I've looked this up and tried different methods I found on-line, all seem to mess up my layout. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div id="allHead">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#allHead {

    position: relative;
}


#logo {

    width : 100px;
    height : 80px;
    background-color: green;
}


#navigation {

    position: absolute;
    max-width: 600px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0px;
    height : 60px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Centering a Div of Unknown Width**

When the div widths are variable, the centering technique below works well. It uses an outer and inner wrapper.

1. The outer wrapper div is set to *text-align:center*.
2. the inner wrapper is *inline-block*, and responds to the text-align:center from the outer wrapper. It uses *text-align:left* to overwrite the text center from the first wrapper.
3. The logo and menu are floated so they will be next to each other.

This is a good technique for centering when the widths can be variable.

In this example the nav will wrap under the logo on smaller screen sizes. This could be beneficial on smaller screens.

---

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/8tx4u94g/)

```
#allHead {
    text-align:center;
}

.center-inner {
    text-align:left; 
    display:inline-block;
}

#logo {
    width : 100px;
    height : 80px;
    background-color: green;
    float:left;   
}

#navigation {
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: orange;
    float:left;    
}
```

---

Here is a layout that will keep the logo and nav together using CSS table displays. Since this is your important main menu, divs were added for the css table and table row for browser stability.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/4ow2x8tx/)

```
#allHead {
    text-align:center;
}

.center-inner {
    text-align:left; 
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav-bar-table {
    display:table;
}

.nav-bar-table-row {
    display:table-row;
}

#logo {
    width : 100px;
    height : 80px;
    background-color: green;
    display:table-cell;
}

#navigation {
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: orange;
    display:table-cell;
    padding:.5em;    
}
```

And lastly, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/zz1706ts/) to experiment with using absolute positioning similar to your original example, with padding controlling the centering. I won't post the code because absolute center is close but difficult to achieve, and the top examples are better.

Comment: This works nicely. However, instead of the orange bar going under the green box after the screen resizes, I would like it to shrink in size. If you could mix you're solution and mine together it would be perfect.

Comment: Try the new JSFiddle above. It keeps the logo and nav together using the CSS table displays, instead of floats. There is also an example using bits of your original fixed positioning with padding to center, but it doesn't center well.

Comment: You legend! Such a good explanation. I've been stuck on this for so long !

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you use classes?

Comment: If you rename #allHead to ".center-outer", you can reuse both center-outer and center-inner together to center other objects that have variable widths within your site. Same thing with nav-bar-table, and nav-bar-table-row. You could rename them something generic like .table-style and .table-row, and add a .table-cell to reuse them as a group within your site. I just put nav in the name so you could easily turn them into id's. Yah, I spent over a day trying to solve a similar issue on my site, so I was happy to have your answer.